# quickly change between multiple static IP addresses on windows 10

Tags: windows-10

I use a Windows 10 laptop to configure multiple hardware devices via ethernet connections (in different rooms on different private networks) and so have to change to different static IP addresses frequently, and also to DHCP (for normal use).  This is laborious and error prone.

I haven't been able to find a convenient way to change my network settings without using the manual method (i.e. opening Network and Sharing, clicking on "Local Area Connection", clicking on Properties, double-clicking IPv4, and then typing in the new address that I had to look up from a text file).

Is there a way to save multiple network configurations and just switch between them?  I've been hoping to find something similar to Mac OS X's Network Locations menu. I'd rather not have to use a command-line script.

Thanks for any advice.

Comment: Have you looked into doing this via powershell?

Comment: I have looked at doing this via cmd (netsh) and powershell (New-NetIPAddress), but I'm not very familiar with how to setup shell functions/aliases in those environments, and I was hoping that there exists something in the GUI that I just haven't been able to find.

Comment: Sounds like a great learning opportunity.